# What's a good word or idiom for the action (or the person) of creating unnecessary work steps when the task at hand can be accomplished much faster?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

For example, it would take me 3 min to email a supplier about an update on a recent purchase, or I could start a new task board, set up an account for my PA, and assign him this task, which would take 15 minutes (so 5 times the amount of time) - what's the word for that type of pen pushing overkill?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The "single-word-requests" tag requires you to include a sample sentence, with a blank where the word would go. The sentence gives necessary information including the part of speech of the word, so you might get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Heath Robinson** is one way to describe it

> doing something simple in a very complicated way that is not necessary.

[[Merriam-Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Heath%20Robinson)

Comment: I have never heard of this. Is it peculiar to BrE?

Comment: @Cascabel I think so. _Rube Goldberg_ in AmE.